SQL -> LINQ - Multiple left joins with null values
I want to convert this sql query to LINQ
left join @categories oc   
     on OC.course_id = t.course_id  
     and isnull( t.offlinecategory_id,-1) = isnull(oc.offlinecategory_id,-1)  

I tried in this way but results are not same in sql and LINQ
join drv in categories
on new { a1 = t?.CourseID ?? 0, a2 = (t?.OfflineCategoryID ?? -1) }
     equals new { a1 = drv.CourseId, a2 = drv.OfflineCategoryId ?? -1 } into cgroup
from oc in cgroup.DefaultIfEmpty()


LINQ isn't SQL. It's the query language of ORMs like Entity Framework. It's the ORM's job to generate JOINs from the relations between entities (not tables, entities). Your Course entity should have a Category or Categories property. If you load a Course object then EF itself will generate the JOIN that also loads the related Category.

No matter what, you should post the entities and even tables. Using ISNULL is quite simply a bug that prevents the use of indexes. NULLs aren't 0s in any database. Either use OR (t.offlinecategory_id is null AND offlinecategory_id is null) or store a default value in that field. If you care about performance the SQL query itself needs to change

@PanagiotisKanavos Just out of curiosity, what if we set the filtered index on nullable columns instead of having default values?

The problem is the function ISNULL not NULL. Indexes are generated based on the stored values and can't be used to speed up filtering on function results. You can create a computed column with the function result and index it but SQL Server won't use it automatically to accelerate functions. In PostgreSQL you can create indexes on expressions, which can be used

The question is incomplete: 1. How are the results not the same? 2. Which ORM do you use? Probably Entity Framework core. If so, please add the [entity-framework-core] tag and a tag for the version, e.g. [ef-core-8.0]. I already removed some irrelevant tags to make that possible.

Please provide further information like expected and current results so we can continue to debug the problem. Otherwise the current version of the question is incomplete

Consider using other syntax which represents LEFT JOIn, look at documentation: Collection selector references outer in a non-where case
var query =
     from t in sometable
     from oc in categories
          .Where(oc => oc.course_id = t.course_id && t.offlinecategory_id ?? -1 == oc.offlinecategory_id ?? -1)
          .DefaultIfEmpty()
     select new 
     {
          ....
     };

